# Does Selenium WebDriver Open Multiple Tabs Synchronously or Asynchronously?

Tags: java, selenium, asynchronous, selenium-webdriver, proxy

I'm using `Selenium WebDriver` with `Firefox` to navigate to a list of URLs. Currently, `WebDriver` is set to open a max of 50 tabs per browser. I'm using a proxy service that allows a max of 1 thread to be used at a time per IP. In other words, they do not allow parallel (or asynchronous) requests only synchronous requests.

I am under the impression that if I execute the following code:

```
navigateToURL(driver, subListOfURLs.get(0));

for (int counter = 1; counter < subListOfURLs.size(); counter++) {
        String url = subListOfURLs.get(counter);
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open(arguments[0])", url);
}

Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();

for (String window : windowHandles) {

        driver.switchTo().window(window.toString());

        // do something with each tab
}
```

that regardless of the number of tabs being opened, each tab will be opened synchronously (one after the other) since the call to:

```
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open(arguments[0])", url);
```

will always run asynchronously  (with the explicit exception if the entire code above is multi-threaded which is not the case)

Can I be confident that Firefox will not send two requests to proxy server synchronously?

Comment: "In other words, they do not allow parallel (or synchronous) requests only asynchronous requests."  Did you mis-type that?  Seems like asynchronous would be parallel and synchronous would be ordered.

Comment: it sounds like you'll want to wait for the page to load in that window/tab.  The calls to window.open aren't an issue... it's the loading... the browser won't wait before opening another tab... you might need to execute a function that returns the new window/tab's readystate to make sure it's done loading before opening another.  Using Selenium to switch to that new tab might also work, but I don't know for sure if it'll wait for the page to load at that point.  (seems like it would...)

Comment: now I'm wondering why you'd open separate tabs at all... is there a reason for that?

Comment: @pcalkins fixed the wording - it's a bit confusing because dictionary https://www.dictionary.com/browse/synchronously defines 'synchronously' as occurring at the same time and if you Google 'asynchronous' it defines it as "(of two or more objects or events) not existing or happening at the same time."

Comment: @pcalkins - "The calls to window.open aren't an issue... it's the loading" - is the 'loading' something that requires the proxy server? In other words, I was under the impression that the request to proxy server is sent and data is received in return and then it takes the browser time to display ('load')  the data. Thus, the next call to proxy server will not run in parallel. However, it seems you are suggesting to wait until page has completely loaded before making another call to proxy server - is this correct? Thanks!

Comment: @pcalkins "now I'm wondering why you'd open separate tabs at all.." - I have found that when I open 5+ tabs per browser everything ends up running quicker.. I don't know why but my testing showed it's about twice as fast as opening 1 tab per browser..

Comment: I'd think it'd be running faster because you are getting the pages asynchronously, but it seems like you are trying to avoid that.  Everything has a sequence in the end, but asynchronous just means that the calls don't wait on each other... doesn't necessarily mean multiple threads.